# Read custom text data from text file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following data in a text file. I need to read the *Service Instance Name, Machine Name* and its corresponding status for every application name. I am coding in *asp.net* console application in *C#*. Any help is appreciated. I'm struck actually.

> ----- data.txt file data ---- Application Name: push
>       Service Name: PushEvent.par
>       Deployment Status: Success
>           Service Instance Name: PushEve_PA
>           Machine Name: machine1
>          Status: Running
>           Service Instance Name: PushEve_PA-1
>           Machine Name: machine2
>           Status: Standby Application Name: pull
>       Service Name: Invoke.par
>       Deployment Status: Disabled
>           Service Instance Name: Invo_PA
>           Deployment Status: Disabled
>           Machine Name: machine3
>           Status: Unknown
>           Service Instance Name: Invo_PA-1
>           Deployment Status: Disabled
>           Machine Name: machine4
>           Status: Unknown

Comment: what have you tried? what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following method :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Application Name  Service Instance Name  Machine Name         Status");

        string data = File.ReadAllText(@"Path\Data.txt");
        var appArray = data.Split("Application ",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (var app in appArray)
        {
            var appName = PullValue(app,"Name");
            var serviceArray = app.Split("Service Instance ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var services = serviceArray.Skip(1).ToArray();
            foreach(var item in services)
            {
                var serviceInstanceName = PullValue(item, "Name");
                var machineName = PullValue(item, "Machine Name");
                var status = PullValue(item, "Status");
                Console.WriteLine("    {0}            {1}            {2}            {3}",appName, serviceInstanceName, machineName, status);

            }
        }
    }
    private static string PullValue(string line, string key)
    {
        key = key + ": ";
        int ndx = line.IndexOf(key, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        if (ndx >= 0)
        {
            var i=line.IndexOf(" ");
            int ndx2 = line.IndexOf(" ", ndx+key.Length+1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (ndx2 == -1)
                ndx2 = line.Length - 1;
            return line.Substring(ndx + key.Length, ndx2 - ndx - key.Length).Trim();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Result:

[image]